# JSF opensource WebShop

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces, shopping-cart, webshop

I am very new in the world of Java EE and JSF, and I am looking for a **webshop** application to sell **software products** that includes features like:

- invoice generation
- shopping cart
- integration with a payment system

My trouble is that I was not able to find anything beside: https://code.google.com/p/openjsfshop/. but this seems more like an experiment and does not compare with any of the open source projects for

- Ruby on Rails: http://spreecommerce.com/
- ASP.NET: http://www.nopcommerce.com/
- PHP (has a ton)

Is there any opensource shop that I could integrate with my project or am I better off using a webshop for a different platform and integrating it with my project using **soap/rest** ?

EDIT: I have just discovered broadleafcommerce, this might be what I am looking for, but I would still like to know if there are alternatives or pros/cons of using it.

Comment: About 70% of the code I write is Java EE related but for average e-commerce I just use Magento. If the customization is not extreme and if 3rd party web service integration is not a key feature I find useless to reinvent the wheel. The Java EE ecommerce specialized frameworks are less mature than PHP ones (unluckily for all Java EE addict like me..).

Comment: I've also created some fully custom Java EE ecommerce, but it takes a lot longer to get to a working demo compared to a simple Magento customization.